# How can i close an already opened window and then open a new window every time i click a button in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I want to open a window using window.open(). but i have to make sure that if that same window has already opened previously , i have to first close that window then i have to open a new one .

Comment: do you have any existing code or do you expect us to write your code?

Comment: I don't think sourav can add a comment as he's a new contributor

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<button onclick="openNewWindow()">Open New Window</button>
```

```
var popup_window;
function openNewWindow(){
  if(popup_window != undefined){
      popup_window.close();
  }
  popup_window = window.open("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
let openedWindow;
let url = "www.example.com"
function openWindow() {
  if(openedWindow) {
     openedWindow.close();
  }
  openedWindow = window.open(url);
}
```

**NOTE :** The `Window.close()` method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the `Window.open()` method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

[Check MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)